# Asmack getting NullPointerException while creating Privacy List

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack, asmack

I am try to create/retrive Privacy List  but I am getting `NullPointerException`. I am using ejabberd xmpp server.

Here id my code.

```
String listName = "newList";

            // Create the list of PrivacyItem that will allow or deny some privacy aspect
            String user = "tybalt@example.com";
            String groupName = "enemies";
            ArrayList privacyItems = new ArrayList();

            PrivacyItem item = new PrivacyItem(PrivacyItem.Type.jid.toString(), true, 1);
            item.setValue(user);
            privacyItems.add(item);


            // Get the privacy manager for the current connection.
            PrivacyListManager privacyManager = PrivacyListManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            // Create the new list.

            privacyManager.createPrivacyList(listName, privacyItems);
```

Comment: More importantly: Show us the stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for reply guys. i am getting "java.lang.NullPointerException" at line "privacyManager.createPrivacyList(listName, privacyItems);" or  even while i am trying to get privacy List.. may be "PrivacyListManager.getInstanceFor(connection);" not return any instence f PrivacyListManager